# Sass Compiler creates wrong code with spaces

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm, file-watcher

I´m using PhpStorm 2018.3 with Sass File Watcher. But the File Watcher converts my code very wrong....

Example:

**file.scss**

[image]

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pqoy147/)

**file.css**

[image]

**File Watcher**

[image]

**Sass Version**
`1.17.2 compiled with dart2js 2.1.1`

What´s wrong? :(

Comment: can't recreate with 1.17.2. Do you apply any postprocessing to your .css files? Also, can you provide your original .scss file?

Comment: Even if I delete the CSS file completely and regenerate it, the problem occurs. :/ I inserted the SCSS file as Jsfiddle. :)

Comment: thanks... still no luck in reproducing it. What is a result of compiling the same .scss in terminal using the same command?

Comment: It´s the same...that´s very strange. I created the project on my MacBook..there it worked... and after duplicating it to my new iMac I get this errors compiling my scss... also a strange thing is that when I edit the style.css and bring `.class` and `:hover` together the editor brings it back to the old bad position....after the second edit it stays...

Comment: it can be some tool that is watching and modifying your css in background... no idea what it can be:( anyway, it's definitely not the IDE issue